# Go - Running cucumbers that uses an API

Tags: api, go, cucumber

I'm using the Godog library to implement some cucumbers tests for my api code, right now I'm only testing one endpoint but I'm hitting an error where it looks like it's expecting to have a server open. I created a httptest server that listens to port 8080 but the tests are failing with a 404.

If I run my cucumber in debug mode they work but if I use the run test command they fail cos the expect an open port `dial tcp localhost:8080`. Could someone point me to the right direction since I quite don't know where I'm failing.

This is my godog_test
`

```
func mockServer() *httptest.Server {
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    u, _ := url.Parse("http://localhost:8080")
    l, _ := net.Listen("tcp", u.Host)

    server := httptest.NewUnstartedServer(router)
    _ = server.Listener.Close()
    server.Listener = l

    server.Start()
    return server
}

func killMockServer(server *httptest.Server) {
    server.Close()
}

func TestFeatures(t *testing.T) {
    suite := godog.TestSuite{
        TestSuiteInitializer: InitializeTestSuite,
        ScenarioInitializer:  InitializeScenario,
        Options: &godog.Options{
            Format:   "pretty",
            Paths:    []string{"features"},
            TestingT: t,
        },
    }

    if suite.Run() != 0 {
        t.Fatal("non-zero status returned, failed to run feature tests")
    }
}

func InitializeTestSuite(ctx *godog.TestSuiteContext) {
    var server *httptest.Server
    ctx.BeforeSuite(func() {
        server = mockServer()
    })
    ctx.AfterSuite(func() {
        fmt.Println("shutting down everything")
        killMockServer(server)
    })
}
```

`

Post step that I'm testing
`

```
func iCallPOSTTo(path string) error {
    req, err := json.Marshal(reqBody)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    request, err := http.NewRequest(
        http.MethodPost,
        endpoint+path,
        bytes.NewReader(reqBody),
    )
    res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    resBody, err := io.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    res.Body.Close()
    [REDACTED]

    return nil
}
```

`

I tried using a mock server to open port 8080 since at first I was receiving a connection refused error, after that I'm getting a 404 which means that my test is not reaching my actual function that processes the post request. I'm not sure if the mock server is the correct approach on this case.

Comment: you didn't add any routes to your router so your mock server is only going to respond 404